# sum aggregate return false for case statement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sum, case

I have have a long PostgreSQL query and below is one part of it which gives error.

Below given query works well if 'TOTAL' order found for particular customer_key and result column return "1" but it return f if 'TOTAL' order not found.

```
 select customer_key, order_key,
 sum( case when order_key  in (
    select order_key from tbl_dim_orders where order_name = 'TOTAL'
    ) then 1 
    else   0
    end
 ) = 0 as result


 from fact_sales group by 1,2
 having
 sum( case when order_key  in (
    select order_key from tbl_dim_orders where order_name = 'TOTAL'
    ) then 1 
    else   0
    end
 ) = 0
```

actually I am  trying to find out which customer has no 'TOTAL' order and below is sample orders table:

```
order_key|customer_key|order_name
1| 2|'Toy'
2|2|'Shirt'
3|2|'TOTAL'
4|1|'Toy'
5|1|'TV'
```

from above table I would need customer id which doesn't have total.

can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate on the customer and use a `HAVING` clause to assert that a customer does not have a `TOTAL` order:

```
SELECT customer_key
FROM tbl_dim_orders
GROUP BY customer_key
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN order_name = 'TOTAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

You seem to know that `GROUP BY` might be necessary, as well as a `HAVING` clause, but perhaps you did not know how to link them together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim Biegeleisen, But I can't just run that query directly on dimension  like you suggested. as my fact table has data for many dimesions, Lets say Store. so one customer can have 'TOTAL' as order say for store 1 and not for store2  thus I am trying to stick with the sales fact table. I just wanted to know why it works well if 'TOTAL' order found and returns f Boolean when 'TOTAL' not found

Comment: @RajeshMhatre Then you asked a misleading question, because my answer addresses the data and information you actually showed us.

Comment: yeah it's my bad. Could you please help me to know why sum(case) works well if 'TOTAL' order found and returns f Boolean when 'TOTAL' not found

Comment: Ohh, sure let me try as this is very large sql query